# Question on four-velocity condition for timelike observers

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, covariance, kerr-metric

I am a bit rusty on GR, I have the condition $u_{\mu}u^{\mu} = -1 $, in some notes I am given that we can obtain:

$$-1 = u^{2}_{t} [g_{tt} +2 \Omega g_{t \phi} + \Omega^{2} g_{\phi\phi}]. \tag{1} $$

The metrics in question are Kerr and Schwarzschild in Boyler Linquidist coordinates. I am also given for stationary obser. at fixed $r$ and $\theta$ rotates with constant angular velocity we have:

$$ \Omega = \frac{d\phi}{dt} = \frac{u^{\phi}}{u^{t}}. \tag{2} $$

Eq.(2) is used in eq.(1) to eliminate $u^{\phi}$.

I am not sure how one arrives at the expression in the LHS in eq.(1), I cannot see how from $u_{\mu}u^{\mu}$, I am not sure why $u^{\theta}$ is also not present. Any hints or general expressions to arrive at this computation are welcomed.

Comment: $u_\mu u^\mu = g_{\mu\nu} u^\mu u^\nu = g_{tt} (u^t)^2 + 2 g_{t\phi} u^t u^\phi+ g_{\phi\phi} (u^\phi)^2$

Comment: @Prahar What happened to the $u^{\theta}$ component? Thanks for your input.

Comment: You are looking at an observer at fixed $r$ and $\theta$ so $u^\theta = \frac{d\theta}{d\lambda} = 0$. Similarly, $u^r = 0$. The only nonvanishing components are $u^t$ and $u^\phi$.

Comment: Ah thats clear now, thanks @Prahar!

Comment: @Prahar:  That should probably be converted into an answer.